# Include dll in C# from commandline

Tags: c#, .net, dll, typelib

I am using the following code to send automatic mails: http://www.independentsoft.com/webdavex/tutorial/sendmessage.html

However I am getting `error CS0246` on the **Independentsoft** commands.

I have done the following:

1. Copied **Independentsoft.Webdav.Exchange.dll** file in the same folder
2. Used the command to generate the tlb file

   ```
   regasm.exe Independentsoft.Webdav.Exchange.dll /tlb:Independentsoft.Webdav.Exchange.tlb
   ```

The output :

> Types registered successfully
>   Assembly exported to 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Independents
>       oft.Webdav.Exchange.tlb', and the type library was registered successfully

I am still getting the `CS0246 error`:

> protocoltest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Independentsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   protocoltest.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Independentsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So I tried this:

> csc protocoltest.cs /r:Independentsoft.Webdav.Exchange.dll

*Compilation is done...!*

I am now getting error while running:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (440) Login Timeout.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
  at Independentsoft.Webdav.Exchange.Resource.a(String A_0, PropertyName[] A_1)
  at Independentsoft.Webdav.Exchange.Resource.d(String A_0)
  at Independentsoft.Webdav.Exchange.Resource.get_Mailbox()
  at Independentsoft.Webdav.Exchange.Resource.SendMessage(Message message)
  at Sample.Program.Main(String[] args)_
```

Can you advise? I do not have Visual Studio.

Comment: Full error is :

_protocoltest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Independentsoft'
        could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
        reference?)
protocoltest.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Independentsoft'
        could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
        reference?)_

Comment: Lordlebu, I have edited in your comments and posts for you. Please add any further information you might have [directly into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18315624/edit).

Comment: Where is `protocoltest.cs`? Is it part of your `Sample` project?